# C++ -- Question about typedef

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
typedef struct IntElement
{
    struct IntElement *next; // use struct IntElement
    int         data;
} IntElement;

typedef struct IntElement
{
    IntElement *next; // Use IntElement
    int         data;
} IntElement; // why I can re-use IntElement here?
```

I use above data structure to define a linked-list node.

1. Which is better one?
2. Why I can use duplicated name (i.e. struct IntElement and IntElement in the typedef end)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither is C++. The first declaration is old C syntax. The second is someone who realized that you don't need that in C++ and then forgot it one line later. C++ does it like this:

```
struct IntElement {
    IntElement* next;
    int data;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

@Q1: Neither *in* C++. Just use

```
struct IntElement { 
    IntElement *next;
    int data;
};
```

`struct IntElement` is automatically `typedef`'d to `IntElement`